# Como utilizar Route en React.js para crear una sub barra de navegación en un child component

Tags: reactjs, component, react-router-dom

Intento hacer una sub-barra de navegación en uno de los component childs de la pagina principal.
La pagina **App.js**, que es la principal tiene una barra de navegación.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Nav from './Components/NavFolder/Nav'
import Admin from './Components/AdminFolder/Admin'
import Home from './Components/HomeFolder/Home'
import Signin from './Components/Signin-RegisterFolder/Signin'
import Register from './Components/Signin-RegisterFolder/Register'
import SideDrawer from './Components/NavFolder/SideDrawer'
import Footer from './Components/FooterFolder/Footer'

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  ////NAV/BURGER NAV/////
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false)

  ////PRODUCTS STATES////
  const [prodList, setProdList] = useState([]);
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
  const [perPage] = useState(5);
  const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0)

  ////REGISTER/SIGNIN STATES////
  const [userList, setUserList] = useState([]);
  const [toHome, setToHome] = useState(false) //to redirect to Home page
  const [user, setUser] = useState()

  ////LOG OUT////
  const clearStorage = () => {
    console.log("Logged Out")
    localStorage.clear();
    setUser()
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem("user");

    if (loggedInUser) {
      const foundUser = JSON.parse(loggedInUser);
      setUser(foundUser);
    }
  }, []);

return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <header>
          {click ? <SideDrawer setClick={setClick} user={user} clearStorage={clearStorage} /> : null}
          <Nav user={user} clearStorage={clearStorage} click={click} setClick={setClick} />
        </header>

        <section className="App">

          <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Home {...props} prodList={prodList} setProdList={setProdList} />} />

          <Route exact path="/signin" render={(props) => <Signin {...props} user={user} setUser={setUser} setToHome={setToHome} toHome={toHome} />} />

          <Route exact path="/register" render={(props) => <Register {...props} userList={userList} setUserList={setUserList} />} />

          <Route exact path="/admin" render={(props) => <Admin {...props} user={user} prodList={prodList} setProdList={setProdList} offset={offset} setOffset={setOffset} perPage={perPage} pageCount={pageCount} setPageCount={setPageCount} />} />
        </section>

        <footer className="footer" id="footer">
          <Footer />
        </footer>
      </Router>
    </div >

  );
```

***App.js***, tiene varios child components y uno de ellos de llama ***Admin.js***. Dentro de este child component quiero hacer una sub barra de navegación para acceder a otras paginas.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import './Admin.css';
import AdminNav from './AdminNav'
import Plantas from './Plantas'
import Libros from './Libros'
import Cursos from './Cursos'
import Videos from './Videos'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

const Admin = ({ prodList, setProdList, user, pageCount, setPageCount, perPage, setOffset, offset }) => {
    return (
        <div className='admin-page'>
            <div>
                <AdminNav />
            </div>
            <div>
                <Route path="/admin" render={(props) => <Plantas {...props} prodList={prodList} setProdList={setProdList} user={user} pageCount={pageCount} setPageCount={setPageCount} perPage={perPage} setOffset={setOffset} offset={offset} />} />
                <Route path="/admin/libros" render={(props) => <Libros {...props} prodList={prodList} setProdList={setProdList} user={user} pageCount={pageCount} setPageCount={setPageCount} perPage={perPage} setOffset={setOffset} offset={offset} />} />
                <Route path="/admin/cursos" render={(props) => <Cursos {...props} prodList={prodList} setProdList={setProdList} user={user} pageCount={pageCount} setPageCount={setPageCount} perPage={perPage} setOffset={setOffset} offset={offset} />} />
                <Route path="/admin/videos" render={(props) => <Videos {...props} prodList={prodList} setProdList={setProdList} user={user} pageCount={pageCount} setPageCount={setPageCount} perPage={perPage} setOffset={setOffset} offset={offset} />} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Admin
```

La primera Route si que funciona
[image: primera Route]

La segunda, que es Libros y Articulos no me carga nada entre el header i el footer:
[image: Segunda Route]

Y la sub-barra de Navegación de ***Admin.js*** es la siguiente:

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import './AdminNav.css';

const AdminNav = ({ click, setClick }) => {

    const handleClick = () => {
        setClick(!click)
    }

    return (
        <nav className="admin-navbar">
            <NavLink className="admin-navlink"
                exact to={"/admin"}
                activeStyle={{
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    color: "rgb(120, 120, 120)"
                }}
            >
                BOTANICA Y PLANTAS
            </NavLink>
            <hr className='admin-nav-hr'></hr>
            <NavLink className="admin-navlink"
                exact to={"/admin/libros"}
                activeStyle={{
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    color: "rgb(120, 120, 120)"
                }}
            >
                LIBROS Y ARTICULOS
            </NavLink>
            <hr className='admin-nav-hr'></hr>
            <NavLink className="admin-navlink"
                exact to={"/admin/cursos"}
                activeStyle={{
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    color: "rgb(120, 120, 120)"
                }}
            >
                CURSOS
            </NavLink>
            <hr className='admin-nav-hr'></hr>
            <NavLink className="admin-navlink"
                exact to={"/admin/videos"}
                activeStyle={{
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    color: "rgb(120, 120, 120)"
                }}
            >
                VIDEOS
            </NavLink>
            <hr className='admin-nav-hr'></hr>
            <div className='menu-icon' onClick={handleClick}>
                <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'}></i>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
};

export default AdminNav
```

Alguien sabe cual puede ser el problema?

Gracias,

Comment: ¿Cargan los componentes `cursos` y `videos`? Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tu componente Admin.js no debería utilizar otro Router. Ya que todo se encuentra envuelto en un Router, sólo coloca las rutas

Tienes:

```
<Router>
            <Link path="/admin" render={(props) => <Plantas {...props} prodList={prodList} setProdList={setProdList} user={user} pageCount={pageCount} setPageCount={setPageCount} perPage={perPage} setOffset={setOffset} offset={offset} />} />
            <Route path="/admin/libros" render={(props) => <Libros {...props} prodList={prodList} setProdList={setProdList} user={user} pageCount={pageCount} setPageCount={setPageCount} perPage={perPage} setOffset={setOffset} offset={offset} />} />
            <Route path="/admin/cursos" render={(props) => <Cursos {...props} prodList={prodList} setProdList={setProdList} user={user} pageCount={pageCount} setPageCount={setPageCount} perPage={perPage} setOffset={setOffset} offset={offset} />} />
            <Link path="/admin" render={(props) => <Videos {...props} prodList={prodList} setProdList={setProdList} user={user} pageCount={pageCount} setPageCount={setPageCount} perPage={perPage} setOffset={setOffset} offset={offset} />} />
        </Router>
```

Quita las etiquetas `<Router></Router>` y deja sólo las `<Route></Route>`

Comment: He cambiado la etiqueta de Router por un div y sigue sin funcionar.
No entiendo para nada el porque no debería funcionar, la sub-barra de navegación diría que está correcta y las rutas también.